# Can i make client 1 in server 1 talk (voice and video chat) to client 2 in server 2 using REDIS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, webrtc, load-balancing, autoscaling

we are trying to build a chat solution where people can voice chat and video chat and message each other, we are thinking of using aws loadbalancing and auto-scaling, the problem here is that each client will have their own workspace, so people who use their workspace will need to be in the same server or else they won't see or talk with each other, auto-scaling will keep spinning up instances, so my question here, if i can connect one redis server to all the servers, will my clients be able then to talk/see/voicechat with each other ?

Thank you,